# Eclipse and Google App Engine: " Registration with Endpoints Server...FAILED!"

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

i've got a problem with google appengine and eclipse.
I'm going and try to be very specific:

I'm trying to make it work NOT locally, so i've done the following:

1) create a project in the google developer console
2) created a google app engine new project in eclipse passing the project number and the api key obtained in the google developer console
3) deployed the app engine project on appengine.google.com, and it says that the state is "running"
4) to do the previous point i had to give the app id number generated in the developer console
5) i set this variable: LOCAL_ANDROID_RUN to false, because i want to do it online

that's it, i get the following error:

2) Registration with Endpoints Server...FAILED!

Unable to register your device with Cloud Endpoints server running at https://myapp.appspot.com/_ah/api/ etc etc

Ah and "myapp" is not a generalization i made to hide the app id of my app, thats exactly what it tells, it seems like the id i gave it is not passed to the url...

I've been trying this for 2 hours, it's getting painful, please help me!^^

Comment: Are you able to access the API Explorer for the deployed app via the http://<YourAppId>.appspot.com/_ah/api/explorer page. Do you see your Endpoints listed and is that working ?

Comment: i get to this screen
http://oi59.tinypic.com/zyikom.jpg

Comment: so i think they are ok, but still not working...